# Add appenders to WAS 6.1 logger

Tags: java, logging, ibm-was

I have old project that was made on HttpServlets and located on IBM WAS 6.1. Project works with slf4k-api and slf4j-jdk binding (i think jdk-binding binds actually to WAS-specific JUL implementation). Now i need to add Appenders so there will be WAS logs (Systemout.log, trace.log etc.) and logs for specific  for every module of this project. As i got know WAS logging dont connected with logging.properties in WAS's JRE, so dont have idea where or how to configure properties for logger.

I tried to search IBM online help but they propose to change log level through console for every project or [create properties file for something](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rtrb_configjavalogapps.html)(actually i dont understand what this guide is about).

Next I looked IBM guides, I found [guide how to use JUL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0802_supauth/0802_supauth.html), but there is not a single word how to CONFIGURE it. (*Funny moment in article author wrote that  article about configuration will be later, and after 3 years author say he wont make it lol*).

How to configure WAS logger?

P.S. Please dont propose change to another API (JCL, log4j etc.). ty

**Edit 1:** Tried to change jdk-binding to log4j-binding, and it works! But WAS dont produce it's standart logs(trace,SystemOut etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to configure WAS logger.  One note, WebSphere Application Server 6.1 went out of service on September 30, 2013, so you should strongly consider moving your application to a supported version of the server.  With that said, the Support Authority article you mention above says:

> Built-in logger level administration for your applications WebSphere
>   Application Server provides a way to set the level for any named JUL
>   loggers, including the loggers you create in your own applications.
>   JUL logger levels can be set using the adminsitrative console,
>   wsadmin, or JMX configuration.

The easiest way to configure logging is probably through the admin console.  There are several topics in the IBM Knowledge Center describing how to do so, [Tracing and logging configuration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rtrb_enabletrc.html?lang=en) and [Configuring Java logging using the administrative console](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ttrb_configjavalog.html?lang=en) are a good place to start.  Basically, using the admin console, you're going to add to the tracespec string one or more logger specifications by including your package/module names and the desired log levels for them.

Comment: I know about changing levels in admin console. But my question is: how to add my own file appenders to WAS's implementation of JUL.

Comment: I would suggest changing the question title to "How do I add log appenders to WebShpere 6.1 and make it clear that is your question.